# Was Isaac Newton left handed?

Tags: biographical-details, newton

I started to see lists of left-handed scientists and Newton is included in all of them. I checked Westfall but could not find the answer. Are there any proofs that he was left handed? I've seen analyses over his portraits, that he was holding a compass on his left hand etc. but I don't think these are definitive proofs.

I know this is a trivial matter but I was curious.

Comment: Other than William Blake's famous [print](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton_(Blake)), what other portraits are there that *suggest* left-handedness? I note that Blake was born three decades after Newton died. I am not aware of any thorough biography of Newton that mentions that he was left handed. FWIW, his hand-written notes do not suggest left-handed writing to me (but then I am *not* a graphologist).

Comment: @MichaelE2 He gives no evidence, he states it as fact without any biographical evidence.

Comment: A [blog on Newton](http://applesandalchemy.blogspot.com/2016/07/newton-was-left-handed.html) makes a pretty strong case that all "evidence" in favor of Newton's left-handedness, including portraits, is spurious. And "a) schools of the time would have demanded their students write with their right hand, regardless of whether the student felt more comfortable writing with the left, and b) Isaac Newton was a deeply religious man and would also have taken it upon himself to write with his right hand anyway."

Comment: The next *question* will be whether Leibniz was left-handed.  Then there will be controversy over who was left-handled first.

Comment: Has anyone checked which way Newton's hand writing sloped, as an indication to his handedness?